# OGC Filer within certain limit

Tags: openlayers, gis, arcgis, ogc

Can any one tell me is it possible to combine Spatial Capabilities (Within) and Logical Operators (And). Actually I want to filter data based on polygon and between certain records.

say we have polygon coordinates and property name id so within that polygon and id between 1 to 10. can any one tell me how i can achieve this

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in case any one need....

```
    <ogc:Filter xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/ogc">
        <ogc:And>
                <ogc:Within>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>Shape</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <gml:Polygon>
                        Coordinates.................
                    </gml:Polygon>
                </ogc:Within>
                <ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>OBJECTID</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:Literal>5</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsGreaterThan>
                <ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
                    <ogc:PropertyName>OBJECTID</ogc:PropertyName>
                    <ogc:Literal>10</ogc:Literal>
                </ogc:PropertyIsLessThan>
        </ogc:And>
    </ogc:Filter>
```